# Yii Framework: setPathOfAlias() returns null

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am trying to put [MaxMind's GeoIp2](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php/tree/master/src/GeoIp2) into my Yii application. Basically, I copied the files under "src" (see previous link) under `protected -> vendors -> maxmind`. The folder structure under my application is the following:

```
protected
|---- vendors
      |---- Zend
      |---- maxmind
           |---- Database
                 |---- Reader.php
           |---- Model
           |---- ...
      |---- ...
```

After that, I created the path aliases into my index.php file:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('Zend', Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.Zend'));
Yii::setPathOfAlias('GeoIp2',   Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.maxmind'));
```

The path works just fine for the 'Zend' alias, but it fails for 'GeoIp2' by returning `null`.

```
Yii::createApplication("FrontendApplication", $config)->run();
echo "Path 1: " . Yii::getPathOfAlias("Zend"). '<br />'; // Correct path!
echo "Path 2: " . Yii::getPathOfAlias("GeoIp2"). '<br />'; // <==== NULL
echo "Maxmind path: " . Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.maxmind'). '<br />'; // correct path

var_dump(is_dir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.maxmind'))); // true
```

Any ideas why this could happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: Yii::setPathOfAlias('GeoIp2',   Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.Zend.maxmind')) because maxmind folder is in Zend folder

Comment: It isn't, they are in the same level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPathOfAlias()` call to create path aliases are created in the constructor of `CApplication`. But the constructor wasn't called yet at the point when main.php is included.

To configure path aliases use the aliases property in your main.php. Like this:

```
return array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'GeoIp2' => 'application.vendors.maxmind',
    ),
    ...
```

Comment: I also discovered that and apparently we posted in the same time. I will mark your answer as the solution to thank for the effort! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The solution:

Instead of calling `setPathOfAlias()` into the `index.php` file I added the aliases into my configuration file (i.e. protected -> config -> main.php), as paramaters, like this:

```
$config = array(
    'import' => array(),
     'components' => array(),
     ...
     'aliases' => array(
          'Zend' => 'application.vendors.Zend',
          'Maxmind' => 'application.vendors.Maxmind',
        ),
      ...
      'params' => array()
    );
```

Apparently, `index.php` is not the right place to declare this. It may be because of the autoloader, I am not 100% sure, but since Zend has an autoloader and MaxMind doesn't, that's why it may work for Zend and not for MaxMind. Doing this made the things work. As you may notice, I also moved the Zend alias path to the same place, for consistency reasons :)