# how to submit a form data to the controller which is within vendor directory

Tags: php, yii, zend-search-lucene, yii2-basic-app

I'am using yii2basic template where I am using `himiklab` search component to make a `lucene` search after doing the the installation through composer `himiklab` directory is  created within vendor then there is  a module which contain controller and corresponding view. I have created a search form in my layout like  this

```
<?php ActiveForm::begin
([
    'action' => ['default/index'],
    'method' => 'post',

]);
?>

<input  type="text" name="name">
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

now i want to call the action in controller inside himiklab directory on the page submit which is default controller having action index.
any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850119/yii-framework-setpathofalias-returns-null